# boost signals auto disconnect lambda slot

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, boost-signals2

I'm trying to do this:

```
boost::signals::connection c = somesignal.connect(
[c]()->void{
    // Do something
    c.disconnect();
})
```

Will this cause problems?

The connection c is assigned only after connect.

lambda needs to be initialized before connect.

It seems capture by value would not work. However, I can not capture by reference, since c is only a local variable.

If it is not a lambda, I can capture the "somesignal", and call somesignal.disconnect(slot). But in the case of a lambda, the slot is itself.

Comment: Not really a Qt question, is it?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld No, it's not. But same problem if replace boost by qt.

Comment: @sehe yes, it should be able to be invoked out of scope. At that time c is no longer available by reference

Comment: I just realized that `connection` != `signal`. I haven't used signals much to date. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extended slot, `Signals2` passes the connection object to it. It's designed [primarily for thread-safety](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#signals2.tutorial.extended-slot-type), but you can utilize it for your purposes as well:

```
somesignal.connect([](const connection &c)->void 
{
  // Do something
  c.disconnect();
});
```

(By the way, as opposed to what the title implies, it's actually not an "auto-disconnection", but the manual one. To disconnect slots automatically, one could use [the tracking mechanism](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#idp204830936).)

Comment: This appears to be called `connect_extended` now